# simple database design with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to design the create an app that should keep of track of completed jobs and status of paperwork for these jobs. It requires a database (MySQL) of the following format:

5 tables:

1. job
2. crew (person who performs the job)
3. store (job performed at location)
4. status (is the paperwork received?)
5. comment (communication and notes)

The following is how tables should relate:

- one crew can have many jobs, one job cannot have many crews   (one to
  many)
- one store can have many jobs, one job cannot have many stores
  (one to many)
- status belongs to a job (one to one)
- comment belongs to a job (one to one)

Constraints:

1. job cannot exist without a store, it also cannot exist without a crew
2. comments and status cannot exist without a job

My sql:

```
USE ppwk;

CREATE TABLE store (
  id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  account VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  secondary_account VARCHAR(64),
  number VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  address VARCHAR(64),
  address2 VARCHAR(64),
  city VARCHAR(64),
  state VARCHAR(2),
  zip VARCHAR(12),
  phone VARCHAR(14)
);

CREATE TABLE crew (
  crew_code VARCHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  address VARCHAR(64),
  address2 VARCHAR(64),
  city VARCHAR(64),
  state VARCHAR(2),
  zip VARCHAR(12),
  phone VARCHAR(14),
  phone2 VARCHAR(14),
  phone3 VARCHAR(14),
  phone4 VARCHAR(14),
  fax VARCHAR(14),
  email VARCHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE job (
  work_order INT(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  svc_date DATE NOT NULL,
  resvc_date DATE,
  level VARCHAR(2),
  description TEXT,
  store_id INT(11),
  crew_code VARCHAR(6),
  FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (crew_code) REFERENCES crew(crew_code)
);

CREATE TABLE status (
  work_order INT(6) PRIMARY KEY,
  status VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  added_on DATETIME,
  closed_on DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY (work_order) REFERENCES job(work_order)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE comment (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  work_order INT(6),
  act_comment TEXT,
  clr_comment TEXT,
  act_last_updated DATETIME,
  clr_last_updated DATETIME,
  INDEX (work_order),
  FOREIGN KEY(work_order) REFERENCES job(work_order)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Question 1: does this sql do exactly what my requirements are?

Question 2: I'm slightly confused with foreign keys. If I add a foreign key to a "job" that points to a "store", does it turn "job" into child table that belongs to a "store"? Or is it the other way around?

Thank you.

Comment: If job has a foreign key that points to store's PK, then every job has an associated store - so you can do queries like, 'find all jobs for store X' because you can iterate over jobs and return those who's FKs reference store X.

Comment: Yes, table with a `foreign key` is called a child. `job` will be a child table of parents `store` & `crew` ;-).

Comment: Are you sure `status belongs to a job (one to one)` and `comment belongs to a job (one to one)` are actually one to one. Couldn't be a Job have more that one comment or more that one paper work. If there are more than one, then you can manage one to many relationship easily because you are already have them in separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Model]

As Long as Store and Crew exist, you can create a new job.

```
CREATE TABLE JOB (
IDJOB CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
IDCREW CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
IDSTORE CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (IDJOB,IDCREW,IDSTORE)) 
TYPE = MYISAM
ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE CREW (
IDCREW CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (IDCREW)) 
TYPE = MYISAM
ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE STORE (
IDSTORE CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (IDSTORE)) 
TYPE = MYISAM
ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE STATUS (
IDSTATUS CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (IDSTATUS)) 
TYPE = MYISAM
ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE COMMENT (
IDCOMMENT CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (IDCOMMENT))
TYPE = MYISAM
ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;
```